# Missing blame information during SonarQube scan

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube

I'm running my Sonar scanner but I keep getting this error.

```
 Missing blame information for the following files:
    16:14:06.813 WARN:   * src/index.js
    16:14:06.814 WARN:   * src/app.js
    16:14:06.815 WARN:   * src/db/mongoose.js
    16:14:06.817 WARN:   * src/db/test.js
    16:14:06.818 WARN:   * src/db/bars_db.js
    16:14:06.819 WARN:   * src/models/record.js
    16:14:06.820 WARN:   * src/fileReader.js
```

I'm new to SonarQube so I don't exactly know what is wrong with it and these files. Are my codes/files missing something? Any insight would help. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an error, just a notice. Blame information comes from source code version control system that identifies who created which code line in a file (`git blame`). SonarQube may use this information to automatically assign issues to users, but if it's not available, it will just not use it. The analysis will still be performed though.

Comment: Oh, is that so? But another problem that I have is that I'm also supposed to link my sonar-scan to the it's website for quality checking. And it wouldn't show up there because the execution fails all the time when I ran sonar scan.

Comment: If it fails, it's rather not because of what you mentioned above. Please post sonar-scanner output from its invocation till the very last message.